# Reordering in a generic list

Tags: c#

I have a list of records that I need to reorder.  Records are assigned a group size (usually 1 to 5 records), and if a condition is present in one of the records, that record should be moved up so that it appears before the current group.  Here's a simplified version of my class:

```
public class Participants
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Order;
    public bool Override;
}
```

The list is sorted by Order (ascending), but in situations where a Participant record has the Override set to 'true', the participant's order should be changed so that it appears before the current group.  For example:

```
Name | Order | Override
John |   1   |   False
Jane |   2   |   False
Ben  |   3   |   False
Carl |   4   |   True
Jim  |   5   |   False
```

If the specified group size is 2, then John and Jane are in the first group, and Ben and Carl are in the second.  But since Carl's contact record has the override flag set, he should be moved to position 3, which gives the following display order:

```
Name | Order | Override
John |   1   |   False
Jane |   2   |   False
Carl |   3   |   True
Ben  |   4   |   False
Jim  |   5   |   False
```

If the specified group size is 3, then John, Jane, and Ben are in the first group, and Carl gets moved to position 1, and the others all get pushed down.

Here's where I'm stuck.  I can loop through my List and check for the Override flag, but I'm not sure how to determine how or where to move the overridden record. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the group size defined? Are you working with multiple lists?

Comment: Hi Ty - thanks for your quick response.  The group size is a variable between 1 and 5 (e.g. int groupSize = 2;),  There will be many lists in varying sizes, each varying from a few records to several hundred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
int groupSize = 2;

var list = new List<Participants>();
list.Add(new Participants { Name = "John", Order = 1, Override = false });
list.Add(new Participants { Name = "Jane", Order = 2, Override = false });
list.Add(new Participants { Name = "Ben", Order = 3, Override = false });
list.Add(new Participants { Name = "Carl", Order = 4, Override = true });
list.Add(new Participants { Name = "Jim", Order = 5, Override = false });

// Group results every 2 records and
// order them by Override (true to false) then Order (ascending)
var ord = list.Select((o, i) => new { o = o, index = i }).GroupBy(o =>
{
    return o.index / groupSize;
}
, o => o.o
, (k, l) => l.OrderByDescending(o => o.Override).ThenBy(o => o.Order)).ToList();
```

This would give you 3 enumerables

```
[0] { John, Jane }
[1] { Carl, Ben }
[2] { Jim }
```

And if you want you can flatten the results

```
var flatten = ord.SelectMany(o => o).ToList();
```

Which will result in

```
{ John, Jane, Carl, Ben, Jim }
```

Comment: The `Enumerable.Select()` method can be used to project an *index*: `list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })`, which can then be used to group by using integer division: `.GroupBy(x => x.Index / groupSize)` ... It's less complex than the suggested `GroupBy` in the post.